# Spark-scala aggregate on multiple columns from a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark, aggregate

I have a dataframe with several numeric columns which are not fixed (they can change during each execution). Let's say I have a Seq object with the names of the numeric columns.
I would like to apply an aggregation function for each of these columns. I have tried the following:

```
println(numeric_cols)
// -> Seq[String] = List(avgTkts_P1, avgTkts_P2, avgTkts_P3, avgTkts_P4)

var sum_ops = for (c <- numeric_cols) yield org.apache.spark.sql.functions.sum(c).as(c)

var result = df.groupBy($"ID").agg( sum_ops:_* )
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
scala> var avgTktsPerPeriodo = df.groupBy("ID").agg(sum_ops:_*)
<console>:79: error: overloaded method value agg with alternatives:
  (expr: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exprs: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (exprs: java.util.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (exprs: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String])org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and>
  (aggExpr: (String, String),aggExprs: (String, String)*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
```

Any idea if this is doable in spark-scala?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at one of the signatures:

> ```
> (expr: org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exprs: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
> ```

The first argument is a `Column` expression and the second argument is a varargs.

You need to do something like:

```
val result = df.groupBy($"ID").agg( sum_ops.head, sum_ops.tail:_* )
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a solution (agg function in Spark accepts a Map[colname -> operation]):

```
var agg_ops =  numeric_cols map (c => c -> "sum") toMap

var result = df.groupBy($"ID").agg( agg_ops )
```